# Kotlin custom getter and mutable list

Tags: kotlin, getter

I am new to Kotlin and I currently don't exactly know how to properly work with getters and setters. I want to write a class product. In this class is a variable `valueOfAllItems` which takes the quantity from the stockList and multiplies it with the basePrice.

Here is my current approach and I think it is not correct:

```
class Product(val basePrice: Double, val stockList: MutableList<Stock>) {
    val valueOfAllItems: Double = 0.0
        get() {
            var value = field
            for (item in stockList) {
                value = item.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice
            }
            return value
        }
}
```

And here the Stock class:

```
class Stock(val quantity: Int, val good: boolean)
```

Plz help.

EDIT: Here is the final solution (thanks to @AyTee and @Tenfour04)

```
class Product(val basePrice: Double, val stockList: MutableList<Stock>) {
    val valueOfAllItems: Double
        get() {
           return stockList.map{it.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice}.sum()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the value in each calculation. you need to add it to the sum.
replace

```
value = item.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice
```

with

```
value += item.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice
```

or you can get it in a simpler way

```
val valueOfAllItems = stockList.map{ it.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice }.sum()
```

Comment: Or the equivalent one-liner: `get() = field + stockList.map{ it.quantity.toDouble() * basePrice }.sum()`.  Though I confess I don't really understand what the getter is doing, and what the backing field is actually for…

Comment: Okay this solves the first problem, thank you very much. But is it possible to asign my ```valueOfAllItems``` instead of using a getter? Because when I debug my program, you can see that ```valueofallitems = 0.0```.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting a fixed value for this property, since the stock list is mutable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So which should I prefer? Calculating with getter or the simple way? I would choose the simple way Aytee provided.

Comment: If your list is mutable and you want the up-to-date value, you need a custom getter. Otherwise, an item can be added to your list and the property will return the out-of-date total. But the "simple way" can be converted to a getter just by putting `: Double get()` in front of the `=` sign.

Comment: For an even simpler getter: `val valueOfAllItems: Double get() = stockList.sumBy(Stock::quantity) * basePrice`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Okay, thank you very much. I edited the final solution to my question. Everything works and looks fine. Thanks you guys.